# MariaDB count, join and group by date without foreign key

Tags: mysql, mariadb

perhaps someone had already encountered the same scenario or issue that I am encountering. I've been searching all over but I couldn't find solution to solve this problem. I have a DB named `machines` with two tables: `project` and `install`. The tables looks below:

```
Project table
+---------------+---------------------+
| project       | date_imported       |
+---------------+---------------------+
| Failed Add    | 2020-06-15 07:28:51 |
| Failed Add    | 2020-06-15 07:28:51 |
| Failed Add    | 2020-06-15 07:28:51 |
| Failed Add    | 2020-06-15 07:28:51 |
| Failed Remove | 2020-06-15 07:34:39 |
| Failed Remove | 2020-06-15 07:34:39 |
| Failed Remove | 2020-06-15 07:34:39 |
| Failed Remove | 2020-06-15 07:34:39 |
| Failed Remove | 2020-06-15 07:34:39 |
| Failed Add    | 2020-06-16 01:22:16 |
| Failed Add    | 2020-06-16 01:22:16 |
| Failed Add    | 2020-06-16 01:22:16 |
| Failed Remove | 2020-06-16 13:17:32 |
| Failed Remove | 2020-06-16 13:17:32 |
+---------------+---------------------+
```

```
Install table
+---------------------+
| date_imported       |
+---------------------+
| 2020-06-15 07:15:57 |
| 2020-06-15 07:15:57 |
| 2020-06-15 17:42:48 |
| 2020-06-15 17:42:48 |
| 2020-06-15 17:42:48 |
| 2020-06-15 17:42:48 |
| 2020-06-16 03:02:32 |
| 2020-06-16 03:02:32 |
| 2020-06-16 12:27:57 |
+---------------------+
```

I would like to count the number of `Add` and `Remove` based on dates from the `project` table
then join the `install` table which also has the total per date.

Here is the expected output:

```
+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
| Dates      | Add        | Remove       | Install    |
+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
| 2020-06-15 |          4 |            5 |          6 |
| 2020-06-16 |          3 |            2 |          3 |
+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
```

Please tell me how can i get this result.

Comment: Are all dates of Project included in Install also?

Comment: Yes, but sometimes not. It only differs when the `Project` has been updated (It is based on timestamp).

Comment: So which of the tables contains all the dates for which you want results?

Comment: @forpas I've tried your query and work like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: BTW to answer your question. I would like it to be able to display either of the tables.
As I am testing right now, I tried to remove the dates, from the `install` table, e.i `2020-06-18` and only retain that date on `project` table. Unfortunately it doesn't show. How can I show even if the date value is NULL?

Comment: This is why I asked which table contains all the dates. So is it the table Project?

Comment: Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=f2d34acc0474536d1b53dc4b123b2f49

Comment: Because there are sometimes `project` table don't have any updates for the day and `install` table has.. or vice versa. How can I display it on the table even if it has no value/entry?

Comment: What is your version of MariaDB?

Comment: mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.13-MariaDB

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: @forpas I played around with the  link you provided, with your updated query. It works as expected. Thank you so much for the help! You're amazing!

Comment: Hi @forpas, sorry if this caused you so much time, but I need your help. From your demo here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=f4c4404a687382f411f204b5e4446826 I actually wanted to add column for the Total of the columns `Add,Remove,Install`? How would I do that?

Comment: Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=3d8673bfc8e56b691adf77603a91ba7a

Comment: Hi @forpas, thank you! I tried removing some entries from install column, it didn't show the total, here's the example. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=eff9f3a1fff0fbf37c1318e809bdd5f9

Comment: Here's the other testing, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=2906e682b5af3599bab0ab052e67de5d

Comment: Use COALESCE() to replace NULLS with 0: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=15c0e44b109340663d25148f74f916b5

Comment: Cool! This is awesome! Tried and tested some scenario and it shows the expected output. Thank you so much @forpas! I've learned something today!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate in each of the 2 tables by date and then simulate a full outer join of the results:

```
with 
  cte_p as (
    select date(date_imported) date,
      sum(project = 'Failed Add') `Add`,
      sum(project = 'Failed Remove') `Remove`
    from Project  
    group by date  
  ),
  cte_i as (
    select date(date_imported) date, count(*) Install
    from Install
    group by date  
  )
select p.date Dates,
       p.`Add`, p.`Remove`, i.Install
from cte_p p left join cte_i i
on i.date = p.date
union 
select i.date Dates,
       p.`Add`, p.`Remove`, i.Install
from cte_i i left join cte_p p
on i.date = p.date
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=f4c4404a687382f411f204b5e4446826).
Results:

```
> Dates      | Add | Remove | Install
> :--------- | --: | -----: | ------:
> 2020-06-15 |   4 |      5 |       6
> 2020-06-16 |   3 |      2 |       3
```